# Bootstrap close function in input field

Tags: javascript, html, function, twitter-bootstrap, input

can someone help me with the close function in bootstrap 3?
I would use the function to close an input field. So the close Button is on the right side of the field.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
</div>
```

But at this time i don't know how to use this in an input field. It is possible? Sorry i'm new in bootstrap an co. :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you include `jquery` and the `bootstrap.min.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
  <span class="pull-right" data-dismiss="alert">×</span><input type="text">
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/130498

***EDIT..*** **Here is an update for placing the close icon inside the input**

```
<div class="input-group add-on alert alert-dismissable">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn" data-dismiss="alert">
      <button class="btn btn-default">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the 2nd example here: http://bootply.com/130498

Comment: Ehm, i have already the function to close the input field. But I would have the "X" button inside the input tag.
Like the "x-webkit-speech" modul :) so the closing button is on the right side inside the input field ...

Comment: Oh ok.. see the 2nd example in the Bootply